Google Apps Script unexpected error in UrlFetchApp.fetch method for HEIC image
I'm getting a strange error while trying to download an image from an URL through Google Apps Script.
The script is a simple GET of an image to download it. It works perfectly for .jpg and .png images, but it simply throws an unexpected error for .heic images.
I got a sample images from the internet just to verify if the issue was with my images, but no, it is with the image extension.
function fetchImageFile(url) {
    var url = "https://3.files.edl.io/4eac/23/03/30/003755-09ee1570-e7d5-4cd9-a2c8-a6380797f81b.heic";

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    Logger.log(response);
    var imageBlob = response.getBlob();
}

Exception: Unexpected error: https://3.files.edl.io/4eac/23/03/30/003755-09ee1570-e7d5-4cd9-a2c8-a6380797f81b.heic

The error is thrown before my log is even fired, so it is on the fetch operation itself. And if I put any URL with a .jpg or .png image, it works fine.
Does anyone knows what can it be? It is an actually issue with the UrlFetchApp class? Is there any other alternative?
Cheers.

It's working for me.

Can you try the script on a new project to see if it'll work? It's also working for me.
